# does LIMIT clause mean constant memory/storage in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

When a `LIMIT` clause is used in a query with a very large number of records, e.g.

```
SELECT *
    FROM my_tab
    ORDER BY column1
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
```

, does PostgreSQL always use a (roughly) constant amount of memory (and/or storage) during the query (1 row in the example)?

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-limit.html) doesn't say much about the underlying mechanism or resource consumption.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not. With an `order by` clause, resource usage can vary between both extremes depending on whether or not a sort needs to be done or an index can be used.

Other factors play a major or minor role too:

- querying from a base table, a view or a foreign table
- width of the table
- data types involved
- size of the table / indexes involved
- whether the table(s) are partitioned or not and whether partition elimination can be applied for the query
- whether a serial or a parallel plan is used (which depends on the structure of the query, the indexes, the partitioning (or not), the DBMS version and possibly other factors)
- resource consumption settings in `postgresql.conf`, like `work_mem` and `replacement_sort_tuples` (see [Postgres docs: Resource Consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-resource.html) for details.)

Answer (score 1):

@Colin 't Hart gives a good answer so I'll just add that `LIMIT` and other elements of `SQL` are logical constructions that say nothing on how a query should be evaluated (including memory usage) by the DBMS. This is a general idea, and not specific to PostgreSQL. This principle is sometimes referred to as logical-physical independence. A consequence is that for example a new index may be used by the DBMS to evaluate a query without changing anything in the query. Some vendors add functionality like hints so that queries can suggest ways to evaluate them, but LIMIT does not belong to this category of constructs. So in short, no LIMIT does not restrict the amount of memory that can be used to evaluate a query.